# What should I be using to serialize and pass my json data?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, json, html, jquery

I have this piece of code to serialize my JSON data.

```
    <div>
            <!-- cut out HTML for brevity -->
            <div class="divwidth">
                <input type="button" onclick="javascript:postBackPart($(this).parent().parent().attr('id'));" value="Test Me" />
            </div>
    </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function postBackPart(div_id) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Parts/Edit2',
            type: 'POST',
            data: $('#' + div_id).serialize(),
            success: function (result) {
            }
        });

        return false;
    }
</script>
```

Now I've seen other posts and sites use either toJSON, stringfy, or serialize. Which one should I be using? Which scenarios should I use one over the other?

Note: I'm using ASP.NET MVC 3 and this code is from a MVC 3 app.

Comment: since you're using jQuery you should use the jQuery.onclick function better then onclick attribute. Also what kinda datas are there in that html div? is it some kinda form?

Comment: It is a form. The form itself has 5 textboxes in it.

Answer (score 1):

`.serialize()` doesn't create a json serialization but a url parameter serialization. See http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

If you use `toJSON`, it must be defined on the object. So native JavaScript objects will support this. But your own not necessarily.

The best way is using `JSON.stringify(value[, replacer [, space]])` I suppose. It calls `toJSON` anywhere it is available letting the object decide how its json representation should look like.

It also allows higher customization by specifying the attributes to serialize and an optional replace function.